# How to call a POST method with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, http-post

I'm building a  MVC project and I have some problems to send the data from my view to the controller or apicontroller.
I need to call a POST method in the apicontroller with the parameters or the object;

```
string fname = "Mark"; 
string lname  = "Twain";
string address = "Some street";
```

or

An instance of the class Person.

1. How can I send multiple parameters or an object?
2. Should I send it direct to the apicontroller or send it the original controller? I have both a Studentcontroller and an StudentInfocontroller : apicontroller
3. Should I use Html.ActionLink or JavaScript $.post?

Comment: Is the user filling out the info you need to send?

Comment: Yes the info comes from userinput

Comment: Then my answer below applies.  I think `Html.BeginForm` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I made a copy of the contraller call and pasted it to my studentinfocontroller : apicontroller and I got some errors in other parts. Just to be sure, is it the best way to put it in the Studentcontroller or the Studentcontroller : apicontroller?

Comment: That's really subjective and dependent on the responsibilities of each controller.  It will work in both cases, but I would think having all student centric actions would be nice to have in one place.  You can have as many actions in a controller as you need.  Just need to return a confirmation page on submit.

Comment: I really like Mosh's course on asp.net [Coding With Mosh](https://codewithmosh.teachable.com/p/asp-net-mvc) you might check it out. [Youtube Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs&t=175s)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a post or many other ways to get the data, but if it's a form and you are using asp.net, Razor handles that for you.  `Html.BeginForm` assumes you have a model that will be updated by the user via texboxes or other controls.  Then some button click will do the call.  Notice `<button type="submit">` tells the form that when the button is pressed the service is to be called and the model object is posted.

This answer is the bare bones of using `Html.BeginForm`.  You will need to dig a little deeper to get a good understanding.

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertStudent", "StudentInfocontroller"))
{
   // style it appropriately
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lName)
   <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
}
```

Controller call.

```
[Route("InsertStudent")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertStudent(Student student)
{
   // do something with the student object received. Like insert or update the database.

   Repository.InsertOrUpdate(student); // assuming you have a repository.

   return View("Confirmation", student); <--- let the user know?
}
```